# How to implement a cancel statement if no data entered

Tags: java, if-statement, exit

I'm still learning at programming and really need some help, I need to make a program with a lot of features and most of it is done, but I'm having difficulty creating a particular line. I'm using a while loop to get the user to input numbers to calculate largest, smallest, as well as sums with a random generated number. I need to program a way that if the user enters the exit statement, -99, before any other data is entered, it will say "You have entered no numbers." and quit the program. Any help would be awesome, and below will be my program code.

```
public class LargestSmallest
{
  public static void main(String [] args)
  {
    //identifier declarations
    int number;
    int numberend = -99;
    int largest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int smallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int number1;
    int sum1;
    int sum2;

    //create a Scanner object to read from the keyboard & input 
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    //create a random object
    Random randomNumbers = new Random();

    //get one random number
    number1 = randomNumbers.nextInt(9); 

    //display prompts and get input
    System.out.println("Enter an integer, or -99 to quit:");

    //loop for number input
    while ((number = input.nextInt()) != numberend) {
        System.out.println("Enter an integer, or -99 to quit:");

        //largest & smallest number sorting

        if (number > largest) {
          largest = number;
        }
        if (number < smallest) {
          smallest = number;
        }
    }
    //calculate final sums
    sum1 = number1 + largest;
    sum2 = number1 + smallest;

    //final statements
    System.out.println("Largest:" + largest);
    System.out.println("Smallest:" + smallest);
    System.out.println("Random:" + number1);
    System.out.println("Largest + Random:" + sum1);
    System.out.println("Smallest + Random:" + sum2);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to end the program with a proper message in case of no user input, you can do something like this :

```
while ((number = input.nextInt()) != numberend) {
    System.out.println("Enter an integer, or -99 to quit:");

    //largest & smallest number sorting

    if (number > largest) {
    largest = number;
    }
    if (number < smallest) {
    smallest = number;
    }
}
if (largest > Integer.MIN_VALUE) {
    //calculate final sums
    sum1 = number1 + largest;
    sum2 = number1 + smallest;

    //final statements
    System.out.println("Largest:" + largest);
    System.out.println("Smallest:" + smallest);
    System.out.println("Random:" + number1);
    System.out.println("Largest + Random:" + sum1);
    System.out.println("Smallest + Random:" + sum2);
} else {
    System.out.println("You have entered no numbers");
}
```

If you want to ignore the -99 and stay in the loop :

```
while ((number = input.nextInt()) != numberend || largest == Integer.MIN_VALUE) {
    while (number == numberend) {
        System.out.println("You have entered no numbers, you can't quit");
        number = input.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println("Enter an integer, or -99 to quit:");

    //largest & smallest number sorting

    if (number > largest) {
    largest = number;
    }
    if (number < smallest) {
    smallest = number;
    }
}
```